# How to install Citrix nsepa in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: package-management, software-installation, 20.04, dpkg, dependencies

I am trying to access Citrix from Ubuntu 20.04.

On load the page requires a plugin to be installed to check for system requirements.

While installing I am getting the following error

```
sudo dpkg -i nsepa.deb 
(Reading database ... 192104 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack nsepa.deb ...
Unpacking nsepa (1.0.0.38) over (1.0.0.38) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nsepa:
 nsepa depends on libnm-glib4; however:
  Package libnm-glib4 is not installed.
 nsepa depends on libnm-util2; however:
  Package libnm-util2 is not installed.
```

I did some search found that these libraries are deprecated and the application needs to use `libnm`.

But the `nsepa` uses `libnm-glib4` and `libnm-util2`. It would be a great help if someone could help me out on to get this fixed.

Answer (score 2):

The software you are trying to install is [deprecated](https://www.citrix.com/de-de/downloads/citrix-receiver/linux/) and superseded by [citrix workspace app](https://www.citrix.com/downloads/workspace-app/linux/workspace-app-for-linux-latest.html) as of August 2018. The latter should install without complain.

Answer (score 1):

1. File a bug report with Citrix to update their package.
2. Easy solution: Until they do update the package, use Ubuntu 18.04 which does have those packages available.
3. Harder solution: You can try installing the 18.04 packages onto your 20.04 system. It's untested: It might break, or simply not work at all.
4. Hardest solution: You can try editing the package's control file to update the dependencies. This may take you down several unexpected rabbit-holes, and occupy an entire afternoon. You must decompress the deb, locate the control file, make the edit, re-compress, test, then troubleshoot. In the end, it might work, or might not.

Answer (score 0):

I just did this myself.

You need to manually download and install the dependencies.

```
wget http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/n/network-manager/libnm-util2_1.6.2-3+deb9u2_amd64.deb http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/n/network-manager/libnm-glib4_1.6.2-3+deb9u2_amd64.deb
```

then

```
sudo apt install ./libnm-util2_1.6.2-3+deb9u2_amd64.deb ./libnm-glib4_1.6.2-3+deb9u2_amd64.deb
```

Comment: I tried your solution and downloaded the packages manually. Now the nsepa plugin is installed without error using synaptic. But it doesn't start. Citrix is trying to start the Sepa check but will timeout after 20 sec. System is Ubuntu 20.04. Sepa plugin is 1.0.0.39. BR Gerhard