# Citrix Gateway Ubuntu 22

Tags: networking, citrix

I need to install the corporate nsginstaller64.deb on Ubuntu22 to access the corporate Citrix Gateway. While installing following error raises:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
nsgclient : Depends: libnm-glib4 but it is not installable
         Depends: libnm-util2 but it is not installable
```

But both libraries do not exist for Ubuntu22. Which options do I have? Thank you for any help.

Comment: I think you need to report this to whoever gave you the `deb` file. Normally, unmet dependencies will be installed along the main package, but that doesn't work if the packages aren't available. Perhaps they need to be bundled with the `deb` file. I can confirm that they are not available for Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS.

Comment: You are attempting to install a deprecated package. That attempt is a dead-end. See [How to install Citrix nsepa in Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1276876/how-to-install-citrix-nsepa-in-ubuntu-20-04)